# html5 audio currentTime doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I don't know why but it doesn't work.
I have this:

```
function stop()
{
  audio.pause();
  audio.currentTime = 0;
}
```

When I change the value of currentTime to 0, nothing changes...that is, currentTime continues having the previous value.

Comment: What platform or browser are you seeing this behavior on? I could not reproduce your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/8SPs7/

Comment: I'm trying with chrome

Comment: Found the problem!! It doesn't seem work well with .mp3 file, your jsfiddle contains a .ogg file...I changed it adding a mp3, and it doesn't work...http://jsfiddle.net/8SPs7/3/

Comment: I have an mp3 and setting it to currentTime = 0 does not do anything. Chrome or Firefox. No effect.. ‍♂️
The only thing that differs:
I pause it, set the time and start playing immediately. (By setting a playhead).
It works as soon as currentTime is != 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it:

```
audio.pause();
audio.src = audio.src;
```

It reload the audio tag, and set currentTime to 0

Comment: I had the same issue and used your solution. However it introduced a new bug in IE11 + IE 10: the audio elements could not replay a sound already played, unless the user refreshed the whole page.

Comment: readyState  = 0 after reassigning the source thus I can't play it.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a browser compatibility issue. Unfortunately the HTML5 Audio API is still not very mature. Consider using a 'wrapper' such as [soundmanager2](http://schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/).

Also see older answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563887/setting-html5-audio-position)