# ng-model for html5 audio element in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, html5-audio, angularjs-scope

Any idea on how to tie an audio element to an ng-model?

I'd like to update a div with the value of the playback of an audio element?

```
<audio ng-model="myAudio">...</audio>
<div>{{myAudio.timeElapsed}}</div>
```

Or something like that. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Simple code worked for me [posted as answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485768/changing-html5s-source-src-attribute-takes-no-effect-wtih-angularjs/32579152#32579152

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by creating a custom directive for your app.  The directive binds a function to the timeupdate event of your audio element.  The bound function updates the timeElapsed property of the current scope and calls $apply to propagate changes to the view.  You can see an example at:

http://jsfiddle.net/ASjRP/20/

## HTML

```
<body ng-app="audio" ng-controller="TestAudioCtrl">
    <audio controls my-audio>
        <source src="**YOUR SOURCE FILE**"></source>
    </audio>
    <div>Elapsed: {{timeElapsed}}</div>
</body>
```

## Javascript

```
angular.module("audio", [])
    .directive("myAudio", function(){
        return function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.bind("timeupdate", function(){
                scope.timeElapsed = element[0].currentTime;
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    });

TestAudioCtrl = function($scope){
    $scope.timeElapsed = 0;
}
```

Comment: Note, I'm just getting started with Angular myself.  Please tell me if there's a more idiomatic way to handle this.

Comment: I don't know what is most idiomatic, but this can be done even more simply by defining a timeElapsed() method in your controller and referencing it from html. You don't need ng-model at all as long as the controller is in scope.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously recommend use of the HTML5 Audio API for an robust player with some real flexibility.  I developed mine from scratch:

https://gist.github.com/djvs/24006c975ff11fd889e3

The standard browser controls for HTML5 audio generally suck, and also often break when you attempt to tie them into something like ng-model or interpolation for sources, in my experience...