# How to get a source path in html with angularjs code in between

Tags: angularjs

I want to play an audio file and my code is below

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="playlist in playlists">

        <audio controls>
            <source src="uploads/playlist/file/{{playlist.id}}/{{playlist.name}}" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>

</table>
```

After this src must be like

```
uploads/playlist/file/3/song.mp3
```

but it's not working for me, what should be done to correct the src path.

Answer (score 0):

change the `src` tag by `ng-src`

See the [ngSrc Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

But it seems that is not enough, see [this SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16721746/1577537)