# video does not played using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular.

I retrieve a JSON data using API.

Here is my code

```
 $scope.camres = response;
if($scope.camres.campaigns.video)
 {
     var v=$scope.camres.campaigns.video;
     console.log("V",v)
      if(v != undefined)
       {
           $scope.videoUrl =$scope.rurl + $scope.camres.campaigns.video;
       }

 }

  console.log("$scope.videoURL",$scope.videoUrl);
```

`$scope.cameras` is a JSON data.I consoled the $scope.videoURL

Here is consoled value  `$scope.videoURL http://13.56.34.247:8001/campaigns/td-YxIiHH5PDHVIFPHrps97F.mp4`

I need to play this video.Here is my Html code

```
<tr *ng-if="videoUrl != undefined">
      <td><b>Campaign Video</b></td>
       <td>
           <video width="400"  controls>
             <source ng-src="{{videoUrl | trustUrl}}" type="video/mp4">
           </video>
       </td>
 </tr>
```

Here is my filter.

```
 angular.module('dashyAngular').filter("trustUrl", ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(recordingUrl) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(recordingUrl);
    };
}]);
```

But it does not Play.How can I play this video?

Here is my output

[image]

Kindly advice me,

Thanks.

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.No, I didn't get any error.

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485768/changing-html5s-source-src-attribute-takes-no-effect-wtih-angularjs

Comment: @Dinesh.This video playing local.But this does not playing on live why?

Comment: http://13.56.34.247:8001/campaigns/td-YxIiHH5PDHVIFPHrps97F.mp4 url is working. just paste into browser